# Mongodb: $exists and $ne doesn't work together

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say I have following documents in myCollection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57861717ae5cdd68414b22fc"),
    "category" : " ",
    "name" : "Category is a space"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57861728ae5cdd68414b22fd"),
    "category" : null,
    "name" : "Category is null"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5786173dae5cdd68414b22fe"),
    "name" : "Category is a not present"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57861755ae5cdd68414b22ff"),
    "category" : "value",
    "name" : "Category has value"
}
```

I want to query the document that has category field and the value is not null or not blank.

I tried the below queries:

1. With `$exists` and two `$ne`

   ```
   db.myCollection.find({"category":{"$exists":true}, "category":{"$ne":null}, "category":{"$ne":" "}})
   ```

I got 3 documents for this.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57861728ae5cdd68414b22fd"),
    "category" : null,
    "name" : "Category is null"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5786173dae5cdd68414b22fe"),
    "name" : "Category is a not present"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57861755ae5cdd68414b22ff"),
    "category" : "value",
    "name" : "Category has value"
}
```

2. With `$exists` and `$ne=null`

   ```
   db.myCollection.find({"category":{"$exists":true}, "category":{"$ne":null}})
   ```

I got 2 documents for this.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57861717ae5cdd68414b22fc"),
    "category" : " ",
    "name" : "Category is a space"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57861755ae5cdd68414b22ff"),
    "category" : "value",
    "name" : "Category has value"
}
```

3. Finally I tried with `$exists` and two `$ne` enclosed in `$and`

   ```
   db.myCollection.find({"category":{"$exists":true}, "$and":[{"category":{"$ne":null}}, {"category":{"$ne":" "}}]})
   ```

Only this gave the desired output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57861755ae5cdd68414b22ff"),
    "category" : "value",
    "name" : "Category has value"
}
```

Now that I got my desired result, I want to understand whats wrong with the other two queries, particularly the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and)

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma
>   separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the **$and**
>   operator is **necessary when the same field or operator has to be
>   specified in multiple expressions**.

So your first query uses the same field multiple times and the second query simply does not filter out the blank value.

Comment: That makes sense. So, now looking at it, if same field used multiple times, only the final entry taken into consideration, just like we do in a HashMap. Good learning today. Thank you for clarifying it.